# VBA - Copy specific value from one sheet column to next sheet row

Tags: vba, excel

I need help please, I have 2 sheet, in the first sheet I record time against different numbers (1 to 50), I want to copy the time stamp over to a new sheet against the same number.
Sheet 1:
[Sheet 1 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejddx.png)

Sheet 2:
[Sheet 2 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ej2U.png)

Please help with a VBA code to get this done automatically.

```
Sub mytry()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRow1 As Long
Dim time1 As Date

Sheets("Time").Select

lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For iCntr = 2 To lRow

num1 = Cells(iCntr, 1)

    Sheets("Rec").Select
    lRow1 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For iCntr2 = 2 To lRow1
        If Cells(iCntr2, 1) = num1 Then
            time1 = Cells(iCntr2, 2)
            Sheets("Time").Select
            For t1 = 2 To 20
            If Cells(iCntr, t1) = "" Then
            Cells(iCntr, t1) = time1
            End If
            GoTo 1

            Next t1
             1
            Sheets("Rec").Select

        End If


    Next iCntr2

Sheets("Time").Select
Next iCntr
```

End Sub

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service...

Comment: What code do you already have and why is it failing? What are you struggling with in the current solution?

Comment: I have added what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest thing I've done, but I'm going to try...

You may want to think about adding a few variables, since you know where some items are going to be on Sheets("Rec"):

```
Dim i as integer
Dim lRow as Long 'Specific to Sheets("Time")
Dim LC1 as Long, LC2 as Long, LC3 as Long 'Up to LC9 in the example for Last Column for Row #
```

Taking what you have and rolling with it, to loop through Sheets("Time"):

```
lRow = Sheets("Time").Range("A" & Sheets("Time").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to lRow
```

I would recommend avoiding the sheet select at the start and specifying the sheets by name as you go, or using With statements (the latter might not work as smoothly for the path I'm going with Select Case).

You can then use a Select Case inside of the loop equivalent to your Number count, e.g., 9 from the example.

```
Select Case Cells(i,1).Value

Case 1
   LC1=Sheets("Rec").Cells(2, Sheets("Rec").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
   Sheets("Time").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Rec").Cells(2,LC1)

Case 2
   LC2=Sheets("Rec").Cells(3, Sheets("Rec").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
   Sheets("Time").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Rec").Cells(3,LC2)

Case 3
   LC3=Sheets("Rec").Cells(4, Sheets("Rec").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
   Sheets("Time").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Rec").Cells(4,LC3)

End Select
```

Then you should be able to have it run pretty smooth, making sure to Next i.  It all comes together looking like:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim lRow as Long 
Dim LC1 as Long, LC2 as Long, LC3 as Long 

lRow1 = Sheets("Time").Range("A" & Sheets("Time").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to lRow

Select Case Cells(i,1).Value

Case 1
   LC1=Sheets("Rec").Cells(2, Sheets("Rec").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
   Sheets("Time").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Rec").Cells(2,LC1)

Case 2
   LC2=Sheets("Rec").Cells(3, Sheets("Rec").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
   Sheets("Time").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Rec").Cells(3,LC2)

Case 3
   LC3=Sheets("Rec").Cells(4, Sheets("Rec").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
   Sheets("Time").Cells(i,2).Copy Sheets("Rec").Cells(4,LC3)

End Select

Next i
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that your iCntr wasn't defined, so I made it easier on myself and just used "i" for the loop since it's just quick to type.  Try to ensure that Option Explicit is at the top of the module to just sure-up the coding and ensure each piece is defined and can't be accidentally mistaken for some inherent reference, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Cyril, it is sort of working, it is brining the info over from first sheet, but if you check my sheet 1 sample you will see that in the first column the numbers start changing randomly, so it needs to add the time to the next sheet in the next column of that number (look at sheet 2 sample)

Comment: @fouriec I made an error in the code and fixed it... LC2 and LC3 were both listed as LC1, which would be bad for what is happening.  As this is an example of 3 numbers in Sheets("Rec").Cells(i,1), you would need to add the other values to your code (zero through nine), and the appropriate last column Dims.